# y ticks in pgfplots are not evenly distributed

Tags: pgfplots

Here is my MWE Latex code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11, width=10cm, height=7cm,
    /pgfplots/ybar legend/.style={
        /pgfplots/legend image code/.code={%
            \draw [#1] (0cm,-0.1cm) rectangle (0.6cm,0.1cm);},
    },
}
\begin{document}
    \pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{

    workload,       EMRSAY,     L-BOUND,    L-MSPAN
    {128M,64R},     15409,      14105,      22906
    {128M,128R},    17501,      15079,      26405
    {256M,64R},     20312,      18509,      29619
    {256M,128R},    24590,      22123,      36960
    {256M,256R},    35152,      32519,      56176
    {512M,128R},    47490,      43012,      64597
    {512M,256R},    62789,      60002,      78179
    {512M,512R},    76596,      66159,      98357

}\PageRanka

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.75pt,y=0.75pt,yscale=.70,xscale=.70]
\begin{axis}[ybar,ymode=log,log origin=infty,log ticks with fixed point,
cycle list={{fill=white, postaction={pattern=crosshatch}}, {fill=gray, postaction={pattern=north east lines}}, {fill=white, postaction={pattern=crosshatch dots}}},
ymin=10000, ymax=100000,
ytick={10000,20000, 30000,40000,50000,60000,70000,80000,90000,100000},
bar width=0.15cm, %width=1\textwidth,
enlarge x limits=0.15,
enlarge y limits={.45, upper},
legend style={at={(1,1)}, anchor=north east, legend columns=-1},
xlabel={Wokload},
ylabel={Total energy consumption (J)},
xticklabels from table={\PageRanka}{workload},
xtick=data,
x tick label style={rotate=45,anchor=east},
]

\pgfplotsinvokeforeach {1,...,3}{
    \addplot table [x expr=\coordindex, y index=#1] {\PageRanka};
}
\legend{EMRSAY,L-BOUND,L-MSPAN}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

and here is the output which I get.
[image]

As it can be seen that yticks are not evenly distributed. How to do that?
Also, I don't want mirror xticks and yticks on the opposite axis respectively.

Comment: You have `ymode=log,` so this is a logarithmic plot and the ticks are accordingly distributed. You can use `xtick pos=left` and `ytick pos=lower` to remove the unwanted ticks.

Answer (score 1):

This is a logarithmic plot, as you have `ymode=log`. To have more or less equidistant ticks you want to make sure that two subsequent ticks have the same ratio. You can use `xtick pos=left` and `ytick pos=lower` to remove the unwanted ticks. (If I was you I'd replace `compat=1.11` by `compat=1.16`.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11, width=10cm, height=7cm,
    /pgfplots/ybar legend/.style={
        /pgfplots/legend image code/.code={%
            \draw [#1] (0cm,-0.1cm) rectangle (0.6cm,0.1cm);},
    },
}
\begin{document}
    \pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{

    workload,       EMRSAY,     L-BOUND,    L-MSPAN
    {128M,64R},     15409,      14105,      22906
    {128M,128R},    17501,      15079,      26405
    {256M,64R},     20312,      18509,      29619
    {256M,128R},    24590,      22123,      36960
    {256M,256R},    35152,      32519,      56176
    {512M,128R},    47490,      43012,      64597
    {512M,256R},    62789,      60002,      78179
    {512M,512R},    76596,      66159,      98357

}\PageRanka

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.75pt,y=0.75pt,yscale=.70,xscale=.70]
\begin{axis}[ybar,ymode=log,log origin=infty,log ticks with fixed point,
cycle list={{fill=white, postaction={pattern=crosshatch}}, {fill=gray, postaction={pattern=north east lines}}, {fill=white, postaction={pattern=crosshatch dots}}},
ymin=10000, ymax=100000,
%ytick={10000,20000, 30000,40000,50000,60000,70000,80000,90000,100000},
ytick={10000,30000,100000},xtick pos=left,ytick pos=lower,
bar width=0.15cm, %width=1\textwidth,
enlarge x limits=0.15,
enlarge y limits={.45, upper},
legend style={at={(1,1)}, anchor=north east, legend columns=-1},
xlabel={Workload},
ylabel={Total energy consumption (J)},
xticklabels from table={\PageRanka}{workload},
xtick=data,
x tick label style={rotate=45,anchor=east},
]

\pgfplotsinvokeforeach {1,...,3}{
    \addplot table [x expr=\coordindex, y index=#1] {\PageRanka};
}
\legend{EMRSAY,L-BOUND,L-MSPAN}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or with `ytick={10000,20000,40000,80000}`.

[image]